# How to locate element from Webtable using selenium webdriver and java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to locate a element from a table, i am using the code below.

```
String part1="html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td/div/div/div/table/tbody[1]/tr[";
String part2="]/td[1]";
int i=1;
System.out.println(isElementPresent(part1+i+part2));
while(isElementPresent(part1+i+part2)){
String groupName = driver.findElement(By.xpath(full)).getText();
System.out.println(groupName);
```

This code works perfect if the table contains more than one element but if it the table only contains one element then it does not work as the xpath is

```
String full="html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div/div/div/table/tbody[1]/tr/td[1]";
```

Is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to access to your element using a relative path instead of an absolute.
If your table have an id, you can use:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("<your_id"));
```

Or a class name:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".<your_class"));
```

More over if you want to use xpath, have a look to the [selenuim documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_locating_techniques.jsp).

Hope that help.